# PHP reading XML with Where Clause

Tags: php, xml, where-clause

Let's say I have this XML file.

```
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Harry Potter - bla bla bla</title>
    <author>J.K Rowling</author>
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Other book</title>
    <author>A Name</author>
</book>
```

Is there a way where I can read via PHP and get the #2 id, or do I have to use an IF?
Like jQuery selector ':eq(2)', or MySql 'WHERE `id`=2'

Comment: nothing actualy, i had no idea to do, searched and didn't success.

Comment: side-note: having the id in a child-element might not be the best idea. `<book id="2">` (+ maybe defining `id` as an attribute of type(ID)) would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is just the second one you can use DOM. It's simpler.

```
$dom->loadXML(<<<XML
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Harry Potter - bla bla bla</title>
    <author>J.K Rowling</author>
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Other book</title>
    <author>A Name</author>
</book>
XML;);

$book=$dom->getElementsByTagName('book')->item(1);
```

Edit: I just saw you say you were looking for second ID, not second element, you need xpath for that.

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement(<<<XML
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Harry Potter - bla bla bla</title>
    <author>J.K Rowling</author>
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Other book</title>
    <author>A Name</author>
</book>
XML;);
$result=$xml->xpath('/book[id=2]');
```

More on xpath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 3):

There is, try SimpleXML parser of php: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: Showerhead did, next to this it isn't the goal to give people awnsers without them giving some input. If he tries something and posts the code and says it still didn't work out i will :).